Suggestions to cool very humid garage
First time home owner here. Looking for solutions to cool a very hot and humid garage (12'W x 28'D x 12'H). I am not allowed to put a mini-split outside, but I can put two vents above the garage door (drawn in blue). The garage also has a high shelf inside. I only need to cool it once or twice a week. What would an ideal solution be? I am thinking maybe a 10,000 BTU Dual-Hose portable unit on the floor, and then extend the hoses 15ft up through the vents? Would love any other ideas or feedback.



Does it need to be cooled, or does the humidity need to be reduced? Cooling a very humid location can result in frozen air conditioner.

How big of vents are you allowed to install? If you could build a chamber behind them, you could actually use a window AC mounted in an interior wall. It's nuts but I've seen it work.

"portable" AC units are generally terrible - adding 15 foot hoses to restrict their airflow more will just make them worse. Trying to cool a 12 foot high space from the floor is dubious as well, though normally you don't need the cooling head much above normal human head height unless you're 11 feet tall. If you can put appropriate vent up there you can mount a mini-split "outside unit" inside, up there - blowing out one vent, drawing air from the other vent. Isolate and insulate it from the interior space, of course.

To cool and de-humidify that volume, and remove the heat from all the objects and structure within, is going to take some time (and energy). It's hard to say just how much, but I could imagine you might be disappointed with the performance of an occasional-use air conditioner. I'd think real hard about whether ventilation alone could make the space more comfortable. An attic gable fan, and an open door to let make-up air in, might work out.

It needs to be cooled closer to the floors so it's comfortable for a few people. I could do two 6" x 6" vents. Sounds like a portable unit is a bad idea. I am very curious about the idea of putting a mini-split "outside unit" inside. Anywhere I can find more details on this type of installation @ecnerwal ?

Cool air wil naturally accumulate from floor level up. So if you put the unit as high as you want it to be cool, physics will take care of the rest. If you put it at floor level, it will be a long time before your head is cool. 6"x6" vents are comically small for cooling an AC unit - if you can't go any bigger than that, terrible portable AC is probably the only thing that could work on that little airflow. Which is part of why it's terrible. It will do better mounted up near the vents with very short hoses, though.

I know you asked about cooling and dehumidifying, but try installing a $200 dehumidifier first and see how it goes. The same heat is perceived differently in high vs. low humidity environments. Lowering the humidity might make the perceived heat to be 20F lower, and make the garage usable again.
The next step would be to add the vents you talk about. These might or might not work. It's hard to tell without seeing the layout and possible air flow.
Installing a portable A/C should be the last option.
